# Can I use iMovie to edit a .mov file without altering the aspect ratio?

Tags: imovie

I created a screencast using Snapz Pro X that gets saved in .mov format (H.264, AAC). I want to just cut a few seconds off the end of that file. The only video editor I know of that's installed on my Lion machine is iMovie '11. Can I use iMovie to remove part of the end of the video, but maintain the same dimensions (1146x1057)?

I tried to import the movie, create a project with just the parts I wanted, and then export via "Share -> Export Movie", but this:

- makes the resolution worse
- alters the aspect ratio
- increases the file size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the video file in Quicktime player and then go edit > Trim or command + T and you can trim the video in the editor.

Save the video and you're good to go.